# How to: How do I make my own shortcodes without plugins?

Tags: shortcode

How do I add a shortcode without plugins? I am going to add a shortcode that will give a count of views on a page.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into this?

Comment: You can add them in themes just like you can add them in plugins.

Comment: The shortcode portion is the easy part, first focus on the logic behind the counting of views on a page.  Once that's done it's relatively easy to make it a shortcode. However, as a suggestion, instead of a shortcode, I'd recommend making it a template tag, that way you can just add it to the template for the post_type you want it to work with, and it'll show up on each page.  That way you don't have to manually add the shortcode.

Comment: thank you, where can I find out more about template tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to modify this a bit to ensure things get placed where you want them but here's something I wrote that counts views on `posts` and displays the view counts for administrators:

```
    //ADD TRACKER FUNCTION TO ALL SINGLE VIEWS
    function custom_hook_tracker( $post_id ) {
        if( !is_single() ) return;
        if( empty( $post_id ) ) {
            global $post;
            $post_id = $post->ID;
        }
        custom_track_post_views( $post_id );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_hook_tracker' );

    //ADD VIEW TRACKER
    function custom_track_post_views( $postID ) {
        $count_key  = 'custom_view_count';
        $count      = get_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, true );
        if( $count=='' ) {
            $count = 0;
            delete_post_meta( $postID, $count_key );
            add_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, '0' );
        } else {
            $count++;
            update_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, $count );
        }
        //REMOVE THIS LINE IF YOU USE THE TEMPLATE TAG
        if( is_single() && current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) { //remove or adjust the '&& current_user_can( 'administrator' )' to modify who CAN see the counts
            //ALSO REMOVE THIS LINE IF YOU USE THE TEMPLATE TAG
            echo '<div style="position:absolute;top:2.75rem;width:auto;display:block;float:left;background:#FFF;border-radius:4px;box-shadow:#333 1px 1px 4px;padding:0.25rem 0.5rem;margin-left:-5px;color:#777;"><small>Views: '.$count.'</small></div>';
        }
    }
    //REMOVE PRE-FETCHING TO KEEP COUNTS ACCURATE
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

Ok, I couldn't just leave it - here's the template tag:

```
function custom_view_counts() {
  $count_key    = 'custom_view_count';
  $count        = get_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, true );
  echo '<div class="view-tracker"><small>Views: '.$count.'</small></div>';
}
```

Then to display it drop this in your theme files exactly where you want it to appear:
`<?php custom_view_counts() ;?>`

You'll need to write css that address/styles/targets the `.view-tracker` class/div.

You can basically build your own plugin, or just drop all of the above into your functions.php.

Comment: Thank you, Tony.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't able to put together the template tag part for you but I've got a deadline to meet. Basically that last bit about `if( is_single() && current_user_can() ) {` - the line echoed after that could be placed into a template tag using the `$count_key` and `$count` at the top of the `custom_track_post_views()` function to create a new template tag that you can drop anywhere in your theme, style as you wish, etc.

Comment: Nathaniel, I decided to live dangerously and spent another 5 minutes putting together the template tag.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, Tony

Comment: So I put this in what file?

Comment: Depends... if you’re making a plugin or just adding it to your theme.  If it’s a theme/child theme, put it in functions.php.

Comment: Ok thank you agiain

Answer (score 2):

There is a whole section on the WordPress Codex on this: [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

```
[foobar]

function foobar_func( $atts ){
    return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

With attributes:

[bartag foo="foo-value"]

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'bar' => 'something else',
    ), $atts );

    return "foo = {$a['foo']}";
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the official WordPress Shortcode API. You can create custom shortcodes easily without any Plugin.

**Code Example:**

```
// HOW TO EMBED         
// Shortcode: [new_shortcode]          

function create_newshortcode_shortcode() {
 // Do whatever you want          
}         
add_shortcode( 'new_shortcode', 'create_newshortcode_shortcode' );
```

Links you can help:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

https://app.wp-monkey.com/generators/shortcode-generator